# What is a good serif font that goes with DIN Black for detail?

Tags: fonts, typography, font-recommendation, business

I am designing a business card, and was using DIN Black as a title font. I was thinking of putting the contact information in Georgia, underneath. Anyone have any experience working with DIN Black as a title font?

Comment: most any would go with it. Hard to say without much more context (seeing the layout, type of company, size of type, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DIN Black has a somewhat condensed architecture, so I would not pair it with Georgia. Look at the relative widths of characters such as the lowercase n, d and o, for example. Minion Condensed or a similar narrow serif face would be a much more satisfactory choice.

Answer (score 0):

I've paired Din Pro with Proforma. Because of shared origin and history I thought they should share some qualities. I didn't have Documenta, which I think, could have been a better pairing.

Comment: Hi user48208, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!